# Jquery/ajax caching issue - Firefox won't refresh modified images

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, caching

I'm working on a script that uploads and crops images. It's jquery/ajax based. The idea is that after image is uploaded, it's being displayed in a div without reloading a page. That's done with jquery ajax function. Each image has then a 'crop' button which when clicked opens a simple-modal window in which one can crop and save the image. After saving it, modal windows closes and refreshes the div by loading it's content again with ajax. This is were I'm having a problem. Firefox from some reason keeps old image on the screen and won't refresh it to display it's cropped version.

I already changed from load() function to ajax() function (with cashe: false param). I added php no-cache header and I'm also adding random string to the invoked url. Nothing helps tho on Firefox (it's fine on chrome)

Any ideas?

Code:

```
function load_posted_images(){

$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/ad_wizard_images.php?uid=1&rand=" + new Date().getTime(),
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#image-list').html(data);
    }
});}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you believe is the culprit?

Comment: If you set `cache : false` in your AJAX request then jQuery will automatically append the current time-stamp to the end of the URL, it shouldn't be necessary for you and jQuery to do it (just a note). The code you've posted doesn't seem to have any problems, could you post the PHP code? Also, is it possible that PHP is still cropping the image when you make your call to `/ajax/ad_wizard_images.php`? If that is possible, try adding a delay to your AJAX call to give PHP some breathing room to do it's calculations.

Comment: image cropping is also invoked via ajax and I refresh image-list on 'success'. So yes, the image is cropped before reloading that div. Like I mentioned, issue was not present in chrome at all

Comment: i'm in same situation, but i can't change file name because i need to overwrite files and they need to have exact same names... So did you find any "real" solution for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, you could try to save the cropped image under a different name (for example append a few digits at the end). Then when you refresh the div, you specify the new image name.

Comment: yes, that worked, thanks! Although I would still like to know how to disable caching for firefox in such scenarios

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Is there any chance you can post the code that you are using to refresh the image?</strike>

Can't you just change the src attribute on the image, to save getting the image using ajax?

```
$('img').attr('src', $('img').attr('src')+new Date().getTime();)
```

Comment: Clair, it's not just one image, there can be up to 10 images within that div, each of them can be additionally removed or cropped. 'image-list' div has to be reloaded as a whole.

Comment: Sorry - misunderstood what you were trying to do. Is it possible to append the timestamp in the HTML that is returned?

Comment: appending timestamp didn't work. I went ahead with changing an image filename as user1181615 suggested and that worked. Although I would still appreciate knowledge if it;s possible to force Firefox not to cache in such situation

Answer (score 0):

I've been in a similar situation, ajax returned content did not refresh, I ended up adding unique strings to the returned content which seemed to do the trick.... just so that the content returned differs from that which might be cached, jQuery already adds a unique variable value to the request but this made no difference in my situation.

Comment: This is more of a comment than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (in the php function):

$time = date('H-i-s');

echo ""

It doesn't change the filename but makes the image src unique and prevents the caching issue.